# Using Shortcodes within functions on Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode, wordpress-shortcode

I have a functions file within a wordpress site that contains various functions that are called up by their relevant hook when a page on the website is rendered.

A particular function is working fine but I have now added a shortcode relating to the Wordpress Plugin "Collapse-O-Matic" with in the function's code. When the page is rendered the shortcode shows up as the shortcode itself in Square brackets! I presume there is something I'm not understanding about how to render the result of a shortcode and wondered if someone was able to explain to me how to do this correctly.

The shortcode is `[expand title="Open" swaptitle="Close"]Target Content[/expand]` and I have placed it in this function as follows (please note this is not all the code inside the function):

```
<ul class="admin">
                    <?php
                    // loop through rows (sub repeater)
                    while( have_rows('item_list_details') ): the_row() 
                        // display each item as a list
                        ?>
                            <?php

                                $date = new DateTime(get_sub_field('date'));
                                $now = new DateTime(Date('Y-m-d'));
                                $diff = $now->diff($date);

                                if ($diff->days > $latest):    //Use $diff->days and not $diff->d
                            ?>
                                <li class='research'>
                            <?php else: ?>
                                <li class='researchLatest'>
                            <?php endif;?>
                           <div class='itemTitle'>
                                    <?php $link = get_sub_field('link_url'); if( $link ): ?>
                                    <a href="<?php echo $link['url']; ?>" target="<?php echo $link['target']; ?>" title="<?php echo $link['title']; ?>">
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                    <?php the_sub_field('link_name'); ?>
                                    <?php $link = get_sub_field('link_url'); if( $link ): ?>
                                    </a>
                                    <?php endif; ?><p class='alert'> - <strong>NEW</strong></p>
                                </div>
                                <br/>
                                <div class="itemDescription">
                                    [expand title="Open" swaptitle="Close"]<?php the_sub_field('link_description'); ?>[/expand]
                                </div>
                            </li>   
                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                    </ul>`
```

As you can see there is a php expression inside the shortcode (`<?php the_sub_field('link_description'); ?>`) but hope it is still possible to make this render correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The function you are looking for is `do_shortcode()`.

Generally, it's simply a matter of doing:

```php
echo do_shortcode('[shortcode]whatever[/shortcode]');
```

Additionally, you are using `the_sub_field()` from ACF, which output directly and doesn't return anything, so you can’t pass its result to `do_shortcode()`.

You could use `get_sub_field()` instead, and capture the output, and then pass everything to `do_shortcode()`.

E.g.:

```php
$linkDescription   = get_sub_field('link_description');
$renderedShortcode = do_shortcode("[expand title="Open" swaptitle="Close"]$linkDescription[/expand]");

echo $renderedShortcode;
```

If you need to check if the shortcode exists before using, you have `shortcode_exists()` available.

E.g.

```php
if (shortcode_exists('expand')) {
    echo do_shortcode("[expand title="Open" swaptitle="Close"]$linkDescription[/expand]");
}
else {
    echo $linkDescription;
}
```

Documentation:

- [get_sub_field()](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_sub_field/)
- [do_shortcode()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/)
- [shortcode_exists()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/shortcode_exists)

Answer (score 0):

inside your code you have to use the wordpress function do_shortcode( $string )

```
<?php echo do_shortcode("[expand title=\"Open\" swaptitle=\"Close\"]".get_sub_field('link_description')."[/expand]") ?>
```

you can actually pass whole blocks mixed with html and shortcodes into this function, it will return a string with everything rendered out.

this works also obviously

```
$output=do_shortcode("[expand title=\"Open\" swaptitle=\"Close\"]".get_sub_field('link_description')."[/expand]");
```

edit: fixed get_sub_field according yivi's input

Comment: That's great thanks for that. If I wanted to check that the shortcode (i.e. plugin) was available first, and if not throw up a message saying "shortcode not available" how would I do that?